# Delete from table and remove file

Tags: ios, file, uitableview, delete-file

I try to remove the file but when I use "indexPath.row" to get the file name it sends me always 0...

This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *stringToPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/examples/"];
        NSString *stringToFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.extension", stringToPath, [self.examples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [manager removeItemAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:stringToFile] error:&error];
        if(!error){
            NSLog(@"no error");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
        [self.manageObjectContext deleteObject:[self.examples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.manageObjectContext save:nil];        
        NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Examples"];
        self.examples = [self.manageObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:&error];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

This is the error when I use `[self.examples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

```
    Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0xb92af90 {NSUnderlyingError=0xb92edb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
No such file or directory", NSFilePath=.../Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/8A5B551A-79A1-40E6-B1A4-C948D9F961D0/Documents/example/<Examples: 0xa2b3ef0> (entity:
Examples; id: 0xa2b0310 <x-coredata:/6871E31A-1253-4195-A84D-61C71B002B72/Songs/p21> ;
 data: {
        name = "Example name to delete";
    }).extension, NSUserStringVariant=(
        Remove
    )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get filename like this:

```
NSArray *fileName = [self.examples valueForKey:@"name"];
NSString *fileName2 = [fileName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `[self.examples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` appears to be giving back an instance of a `Songs` object. Your use of this in the `stringWithFormat:` results in a call to the `description` method on that object. That certainly is not what you want.

Split the code up a bit:

```
Songs *songs = [self.examples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *filename = ... // some call on songs to get the filename
```

Only you know how to get the filename from the `songs` object.

FYI - the way you build the path is all wrong. Do some searching for the proper way to get a reference to the `Documents` folder. And do not use `stringWithFormat:` to build up a path. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`.

Comment: I use this also but this also can't help me I can't get the current row name (this which I delete)...
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/examples/"];
I want to delete the file which name is in the table etc. my row in table is "Example name to delete" when I slide my finger to delete the row I want to delete the file also but I can't get the name of the row. The file name is the row's name and I can't delete the file because I can't get row's name in variable...